# How do you say "I already can tell (understand) X"?

Tags: usage, phrases, phrase-requests

I want to say the equivalent of

> I can already tell (understand) that game X is (going to be) harder
>   than game Y.

For instance, I've already beat game Y. And even though I've only just started playing game X, I can already tell it is going to be harder than game Y. That's what I'm trying to convey in a sense.

I know that to say "game X is harder than game Y" you would say:

> ゲームXのほうがゲームYより難しいです。

But I'm unsure how to add on "I already know/understand/can tell that.."

My best guess is something like:

> ゲームXのほうがゲームYより難しいともうわかった。

But I'm not sure if that is right or if there is a better way to say it.

Comment: How about ~ことはわかる。=ゲームXのほうがゲームYより難しいことはもうわかった。You also check out  既に in your favorite dictionary.  http://www.japandict.com/%E6%97%A2%E3%81%AB

Comment: I thought of using こと as well. But I need someone who actually **knows** what is right/wrong to confirm which ways are correct. I'm just taking an educated guess. D:

Comment: I have a bachelors in Japanese, lived in Japan an accumulative 15 years, and also have JLPT N1 & L1.  Feel free to wait around though.

Comment: Sorry, the way you used "How about" made me think you were unsure (such as another beginner like myself). You should have submitted that as an *answer* if you knew you could say it that way. :P

Comment: There's a lot of ways to skin a cat. Also, the community here is pretty brutal and what constitutes an answer.  If I can't provide a bunch of links, examples, and whatnot then I usually just make a suggestion in the comments.  For the record, I also never really learned the mechanics of Japanese, so explaining isn't my strong suit. ;)

Comment: Ahh, I see. Didn't know that since I'm new to here. Thanks for letting me know I can use こと! :D

Comment: @kiss-o-matic I haven't been on here too long, but I wouldn't say the community is brutal.  From what I've seen, the community behavior comparable to several other SE sites.  (Most people are polite, as long as you play by the rules, though not everyone does.)  That said, I also prefer to give comments many times because I don't want to put in the effort to make write a good answer.

Comment: I'm on Stack Overflow the most, where a simple answer is generally praised.  I've not found this place to be the same.   Just my experience.  Not trying to dog the place.  (I'm still here!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really like xの方がyより in this order.
I would rather say it like

> ゲームXはゲームYより難しいのはもうわかっている。

or

> ゲームYよりゲームXの方が難しいのはもうわかっている。

Comment: IMHO 'もうわかっている' could be taken negative according to the situation. Maybe it would be better without 'もう' or using 'よくわかっている' instead?

Comment: I agree with you but in this *I can already tell that game X is harder than game Y* situation, I don't think there is room for confusion. Plus, we need to convey the *already* somehow.

Answer (score -2):

for "can tell", as in I have the feeling that : the most natural would be "気がする"

```
ゲームXのほうがゲームYより難しい気がします
```

for "can tell", as in after thinking about it and i'm sure of it : "ことはわかる" as kiss-o-matic said would be right

Comment: 気がする is too weak to express *I can tell*.

Comment: @oldergod Yeah, you may be right.  In the other hand  わかる may seem to strong. So that's why, if you read the all answer, I put both depending on the nuance you are looking for.